# Netbeans 8.0 JavaDoc java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, javadoc, stack-overflow, netbeans-8

I have a problem with JavaDoc.

I try to generate the JavaDoc for my project, but Netbeans 8 returns this error:

This is the error code: http://paste2.org/XaGpfs0t

I'm on Ubuntu 14.

any idea?

Thank you for help!

EDIT:

```
    ant -f /home/mex/NetBeansProject/web_search/web_engines_evaluator -Dnb.internal.action.name=javadoc javadoc
    init:
    Generating Javadoc
    Javadoc execution
    Loading source file /home/mex/NetBeansProject/web_search/web_engines_evaluator/src/web_engines_evaluator/ConnectYahoo.java...
    Loading source file /home/mex/NetBeansProject/web_search/web_engines_evaluator/src/web_engines_evaluator/DistanceComparator.java...
    Loading source file /home/mex/NetBeansProject/web_search/web_engines_evaluator/src/web_engines_evaluator/GsonBingItem.java...
    Loading source file /home/mex/NetBeansProject/web_search/web_engines_evaluator/src/web_engines_evaluator/GsonDistanceItem.java...
    Loading source file /home/mex/NetBeansProject/web_search/web_engines_evaluator/src/web_engines_evaluator/GsonGoogleItem.java...
    Loading source file /home/mex/NetBeansProject/web_search/web_engines_evaluator/src/web_engines_evaluator/GsonYahooItem.java...
    Loading source file /home/mex/NetBeansProject/web_search/web_engines_evaluator/src/web_engines_evaluator/ParserStimoli.java...
    Loading source file /home/mex/NetBeansProject/web_search/web_engines_evaluator/src/web_engines_evaluator/SLemmatizer.java...
    Loading source file /home/mex/NetBeansProject/web_search/web_engines_evaluator/src/web_engines_evaluator/SearchItem.java...
    Loading source file /home/mex/NetBeansProject/web_search/web_engines_evaluator/src/web_engines_evaluator/SemanticDistance.java...
    Loading source file /home/mex/NetBeansProject/web_search/web_engines_evaluator/src/web_engines_evaluator/StHttpRequestYahoo.java...
    Loading source file /home/mex/NetBeansProject/web_search/web_engines_evaluator/src/web_engines_evaluator/Stopwords.java...
    Loading source file /home/mex/NetBeansProject/web_search/web_engines_evaluator/src/web_engines_evaluator/Utils.java...
    Constructing Javadoc information...
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavaTokenizer.readToken(JavaTokenizer.java:566)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Scanner.nextToken(Scanner.java:115)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.nextToken(JavacParser.java:296)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.literal(JavacParser.java:754)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.literal(JavacParser.java:654)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term3(JavacParser.java:1152)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term2(JavacParser.java:904)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term1(JavacParser.java:875)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term(JavacParser.java:831)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term(JavacParser.java:811)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseExpression(JavacParser.java:774)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.arguments(JavacParser.java:1774)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.arguments(JavacParser.java:1789)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term3(JavacParser.java:1250)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term2(JavacParser.java:904)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term1(JavacParser.java:875)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term(JavacParser.java:831)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term(JavacParser.java:811)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseExpression(JavacParser.java:774)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parExpression(JavacParser.java:2255)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2439)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2347)
atcom.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2312)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2444)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2347)

    javadoc: error - fatal error
    1 error
    /home/mex/NetBeansProject/web_search/web_engines_evaluator/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1233: Javadoc returned 1
    BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: Could you please post the stacktrace here?

Comment: Could you explain me how?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for this bug: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=238833

Comment: @davide4688 edit, copy, paste, select and format by pressing the `{}` button

Comment: It is a bug, data dependent, that is: on some javadoc construct. Comment parts out/in till you find the offending syntax. Maybe a recursive `/** @see #f */ void f()`.

Comment: I found the error, is this import:

import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;


but i need this import, i can't remove it !!